# exclude folder from windows share

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I'm more familiar with Linux/Samba so please bear with me. 
Single Windows7 share, how do I exclude sub directories inside the root shared folder that match a pattern from being visible to share users?

In samba this is trivial

```
[shareName]
    veto files = /*.private/
```

Is there similar functionality in Windows?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/550275/veto-files-on-a-windows-share

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'm out of luck since I'm using Windows 7.